# preg_match_all multidimensional array output looping? PHP

Tags: php, loops, multidimensional-array, foreach, preg-match-all

I am currently running a `preg_match_all` on a string that is looking for phone numbers using regular expressions. When it finds a match it makes note of the offset position within the string.

**preg_match_all Example:**

```
preg_match_all('/\b\/?\d?[-.]?\s?\(?\d{3}\)?\s?[-.]?\d{3}[-.]?\d{4}\b/', $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

**Using print_r**

```
echo print_r($matches, true).BR;
```

**Outputs:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 666.666.6666
                    [1] => 1190
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 555-555-5555
                    [1] => 1206
                )

        )

)
```

**The problem:** How do I loop through the matches and echo out the number, and the offset position?

Comment: Could you provide your input string?

Comment: The strings I am parsing through are email body contents and are too long to post here, and are private emails. All the matching and such is good, I just need to know how I can loop through the array of data that it finds in the example above. this way I can store both the number and its offset position into variables or a database if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a foreach loop :

```
foreach ($matches[0] as $match) { // use first array item to loop through since the matches are in its sub-array
    echo "Number = " . $match[0] . " | Offset = " . $match[1] . "\r\n";
}
```

Output :

> ```
> Number = 666.666.6666 | Offset = 1190
> Number = 555.555.5555 | Offset = 1206
> ```

Comment: I had done that exact foreach loop in my code but apparently, my fail was not specifically targeting $match[0] & $match[1] - Thanks!

Comment: @Meta Do you mind my asking why you weren't targeting them correctly? You showed the `print_r()` output, it clearly identifies them that way. As someone who spend a huge amount of time answering newbie questions here, I wonder what the mental block is to getting things like this right when you can see it right in front of your eyes.

Comment: @Barmar been up working on a project for almost 48 hrs straight and I am not 100% familiar with multidimensional arrays and am recently returning to programming after a lengthy break, so I am still quite rusty.